# Sudo cron job using arp-scan gives empty output

Tags: bash, cron, sudo, arp

I made a script called `hello.sh` and it contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "$( arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet )\n"
printf "test\n"
```

after making it executable (`chmod o+x`) and running it (`./hello.sh >> file.txt`) I get the correct output in `file.txt` (which is the arp-scan result and the string "test"). But after adding the following line to  `crontab -e`:

```
*/1 * * * *  /path/to/hello.sh >> /path/to/file.txt
```

I get the following output:

```
test

test

test
```

As you can see there is a empty string returned by the `arp-scan` part. How can I get arpscan working with cron?

**Additional info:** Everything is done after logging in as sudo (`sudo -i`). `arp-scan` needs sudo. I am running this on Fedora 20.

Comment: Provide the full path to `arp-scan` in the script, `cron` runs with a minimal environment and it may not be in the path.  Also, do you mean you've added this to root's `crontab` rather than your own?  `cron` isn't going to honour anything to do with sudo if you add this to your own `crontab`.

Comment: What EightBitTony said. Also, why create a script for it at all? Just run `arp-scan` directly from `cron`.

Comment: @EightBitTony It worked by giving the full path. @ terdon this was a simplified version of the script (stackexchange asks for this). The output of arp-scan is actually processed by the real script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` runs with a very minimal environment and a reduced path.

It's always safest in scripts designed to be executed by `cron` to ensure all commands have the full path provided, or the script sets its own PATH variable.

Try adding the full path to the `arp-scan` command.